# Sequelize converted float to int NodeJS for MySQL DB while read

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, sequelize.js

I have the following data in MySQL database:

```
Column: Volume
Value:
3495303.0
3495123.8
3484616.8
3482624.8
3474865.5
3434217.5
3407878.0
```

I use the following code to read from the database:

```
let query = {
    where: {
        id: id
    },
    order: [
        ['time', 'DESC']
    ],
}
let result = await markets.findAll(query);
```

At the following is markets.js

```
let markets = dbConnection.connection.define(
    'markets', {
        ...,
        volume: Sequelize.FLOAT,
        ...,
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    }
);

module.exports = markets;
```

However, when column "volume" is read from the database, all the number is converted into int rather than float.
I manually executed SQL script generated by Sequelize, and I can see the value of volume has decimals.

However, when the data is loaded into my JSON object "result", the value for volume becomes integer.

I have tried with changing the definition in markets.js
from

```
volume: Sequelize.FLOAT,
```

to

```
volume: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
```

But it does not change a thing.
The definition of volume in MySQL is:

```
volume         float
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured it out.

The reason being it is doing the wrong thing is the number for volume is overwhelming. There are volume value like "`1.0775351E7`" which is beyond the capability of `FLOAT` calculation.
I changed the data type in both database and node code to `DOUBLE` and it is working fine now.